# What exactly is the Openssl -md flag used for?

Tags: openssl

I was just playing around with openssl for decrypting some files.

The command I ended up using looks like so (found it elsewhere):

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -iv 0 -in in.enc -out out.data
```

I was looking at the part that says `-md sha256`. I tried looking in [in the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl.html), but it only has flags where a number after "md" is defined. But I couldnt find what the `-md` flag is and what it is used for.

I assume that it is a hash function which in someway is used internally in the encryption/decryption function that I am defining.
But what *exactly* it is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The openssl subcommands have their own man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/), in this case the subcommand is `enc`. So you have to run `man openssl-enc` to find the documentation.

The option `-md` specifies:

> `-md` digest
> Use the specified digest to create the key from the passphrase.  The default algorithm is sha-256.

Apparently `digest` i[s a synonym for `hash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function):

> A cryptographic hash function (CHF) is a mathematical algorithm that maps data of an arbitrary size (often called the "message") to a bit array of a fixed size (the "hash value", "hash", or "message digest").